# prove this inequality $a^n>b^n+c^n$

Tags: inequality

We know a,b and c are positive and
 $a^2=b^2+c^2$
How we can conclude this inequality:
$a^n>b^n+c^n$  , $n>2$

I tried Binomial Theorem  but I can't prove this.
Thanks

Comment: Hi matinhabi. Your question is very interesting, but it would be very useful if you had more details (what already do you  have tried, your efforts, where you found this question, and so on). This will help a lot the community helping you to find your way toward the solution!

Comment: My teacher in high school give it to me.

Comment: what was the topic your teacher was teaching you when he/she asked this question?

Comment: He teaches Geometry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$a^n=(a^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}=(b^2+c^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}>b^n+c^n$$

the inequality is equivalent to $(b^2+c^2)^n>(b^n+c^n)^2$ - this is not hard to prove by Newton's binomial formula

Comment: Can you continue? I tried Newton's binomial formula but can't do anything

Comment: $n>2\implies(b^2+c^2)^n>b^{2n}+n(b^2c^{2n-2}+b^{2n-2}c^2)+c^{2n}$ by Newton. now apply $x+y\ge 2\sqrt{xy}$ for the middle part and you're done!

Comment: How about the case where $n$ is not an even integer?

Answer (score 2):

If $n=2m$ is even, then this is straightforward:
$$ a^n=(a^2)^m=(b^2+c^2)^m> b^{2m}+c^{2m}=b^n+c^n$$

If $n>2$ is odd, then since $n-1$ is even it follows that
$$ a^{n}=a\cdot a^{n-1}\geq a(b^{n-1}+c^{n-1})$$
using either equality if $n-1=2$, or what we have shown above if $n-1>2$.

Finally, $a^2=b^2+c^2$ with $a,b,c>0$ implies that $a>b$ and $a>c$, hence
$$ a(b^{n-1}+c^{n-1})>b\cdot b^{n-1}+c\cdot c^{n-1}=b^n+c^n$$

Comment: Can we use induction?

Comment: Probably, but it's not necessary

Answer (score 2):

$a^2=b^2+c^2\iff 1=(\frac ba)^2+(\frac ca)^2$ and clearly $\frac ba <1$ and $\frac ca <1$. Hence $$1=(\frac ba)^2+(\frac ca)^2>(\frac ba)^3+(\frac ca)^3>(\frac ba)^4+(\frac ca)^4>......>(\frac ba)^n+(\frac ca)^n$$

Thus $$1>(\frac ba)^n+(\frac ca)^n\iff a^n>b^b+c^n$$